# Add pagination to for each taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy, pagination

I am tring to add a line of code that paginate the taxonomies to serveral pages 
this lin is a function i created called

> wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav();

but every time i add the function after the foreach close paracket the pagination created but all the pages have the same taxonomy in page 1

the code that i use is this

```
<?php get_header('category');?>

 <section class="gallery-block compact-gallery">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row mx-auto justify-content-center  ">
                 <?php
     $term = get_queried_object();
    //  if($term->post_parent !=0 ){
        $term_id = $term->term_id;
        $taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
        $termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
         // echo    $postcat ;
         if ( !empty( $termchildren )){
         foreach ($termchildren  as $child) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                 ?>
                 <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 item bg-white mb-5 p-0 mr-2">
                     <a class="lightbox" href="<?php  echo get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy_name );?>">
                     <img class="img-fluid image w-100 h-50" src=" <?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/'.$term->name.'.png');?>">
                             <span class="description">
                             <span class="description-heading tajawal "><?php echo $term->name ;?></span>
                             <span class="description-body"></span>
                                 </span>
                                 </a>
                 </div>


                 <?php } wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); }else { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That pagination is for posts, whereas you are trying to paginate terms.

One approach is to create the pagination for yourself:

```
$term_id = $term->term_id;
$taxonomy_name = $term->taxonomy;
$termchildren = get_term_children($term_id, $taxonomy_name);

$per_page = 10;
$page  = get_query_var('page');
$paged = get_query_var('paged');
$total_pages = ceil(count($termchildren) / $per_page);

$current_page = ($paged ? $paged : ($page ? $page : 1));
$offset = (($current_page - 1) * $per_page);

$term_children = array_slice($term_children, $offset, $per_page);
```

Untested, but that's a starting point. You can use `$total_pages` and `$current_page` to build the pagination links.

Comment: the function i use  works but it seems some thing not correct with it , that means it may work for post and terms too .. right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the pagination is typically for posts only, and you want to paginate terms (basically just a dumb array). Give this code a try and see how you get on, or you can try a Google for `WordPress paginate terms`

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, you're asking about paginating terms in this question. But posts and custom posts are both `post` types, so in theory should paginate in the same way. I've not looked at that wp_beginner code however. You can always raise that as a new question.